# Preloader doesn't stop and wont transition to main page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My preloader wont stop loading and it doesn't want to transition to the main page.
The preloader is supposed to load for 3-4 seconds and then automatically transition to the page. I've tried removing things in the jquery/javascript. But I couldn't find an option that fixes it.

Also looked on the web for solutions, but none of them helped me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // site preloader -- also uncomment the div in the header and the css style for #preloader
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.js div#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    background: #333 url('http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<?php
/**
* Maintenance mode template. This is shown to anyone that is logged out or not an administrator!
* @package    maintenance-mode
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2016, ZartanLOL
* @license    GPL2+
*/
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset ="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/css/maintenance.css', dirname( __FILE__ ) ); ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/css/mobile.css', dirname( __FILE__ ) ); ?>">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'assets/js/preload.js', dirname( __FILE__ ) ); ?>"></script>


  <title>Maintenance Mode</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="preloader"></div>
  <div class="maintenance-mobile">
    <div class="maintenance-mobile-text">
      <h1>Maintenance</h1>
      <p>This website is currently undergoing scheduled maintenance. We will be back shortly! Sorry for the inconvenience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="maintenance-container">
      <a class="maintenance-login" href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>">Go to Login Page</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="maintenance-container">
    <a class="maintenance-login" href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>">Go to Login Page</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'd recommend you read this:
https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/

You are using jQuery 3, but you are using functions that have been deprecated since jquery 1.10+ or so.

`.load()` has been removed from jQuery 3. So has document ready.

> Event
>
> Breaking change: .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed
>
> Breaking change: .on("ready", fn) removed
>
> Breaking change: event.pageX and event.pageY normalization removed
>
> Breaking change:
>   jQuery.event.props and jQuery.event.fixHooks removed
>
> Breaking change:
>   Delegated events with bad selectors throw immediately
>
> Deprecated:
>   .bind() and .delegate()

User the proper modern-day jQuery functions such as

```
$(function(){ // this replaces document.ready
  $(window).on("load", function(){
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

A little bit more information from the jQuery website to confirm:

> These methods are shortcuts for event operations, but had several API
>   limitations. The event .load() method conflicted with the ajax .load()
>   method. The .error() method could not be used with window.onerror
>   because of the way the DOM method is defined. **If you need to attach
>   events by these names, use the .on() method, e.g. change
>   $("img").load(fn) to $(img).on("load", fn).**

--
in response to the comments; if you want to just simply delay the loader's removal, it would go like this:

```
$(function(){ // this replaces document.ready
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
   }, 1500);
});
```

-- Have you checked your console (f12 on windows) to see if there are no errors in it?
-- Did you check in your source (ctrl + U on windows) whether the javascript is actually getting included properly?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm pretty bad with jquery. SO that's why. - Now I sometimes have the problem that the page loads and the preloader dissapears and sometimes the preloader just keeps spinning. What would I need to do to always have the preloader load for 3 seconds and only load it once every hour or 2?

Comment: @BPrepper this more than likely has to do with caching. You see, caching doesn't always trigger the `$(window).on("load")` function. It's quite bad practice, actually. Let me try and find you a way to do this. But yes, you could just do the preloader for a steady 3 seconds (though this is VERY long, I wouldn't recommend you go over 1,5 seconds!) with the `setTimeout()` function. see this for more information on `setTimeout()`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Oh, may I recommend you try while putting your javascript into the footer instead of the header? After building a few hundred websites, I noticed that especially **google chrome** tends to mess up javascript trigger times when they are included in the header. (keep jQuery in the header, but any functioning script in the footer/just before the </body> tag)

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to use `setTimeout(function(){ myWindow.close() }, 1500);`  but it doesn't work. I tried changing the function name. But it still loads permanently. I places this settimeout before the last });

Comment: where did `mywindow.close()` come from? Shouldn't it just be ` $('#preloader').fadeOut()` within a function wrapper? Hold on, let me update my answer

Comment: I fixed it, the token on line 8 was too much, had to delete that. :)

Comment: @BPrepper sorry, I forgot to remove the ending tag of the removed `$(window).load()`. I fixed it in my answer as well. So, does it work now?

Comment: I had the same problem but just on some devices for some reason, like an ipad. But using the "proper modern-day" example you gave made it work for me.